# Disabled clicking function in div reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div  className="check" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={name} />

.check{
 pointer-events: none !important;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

pointer-events is not working. Inside the {name} i have contentEditable, so when i click on it , it is working, what is the way to give mouse arrow disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the same approach?

```
    <div onClick={()=> alert('clicked')} className="check" 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'name'}} />
```

once we add the 'check' class, click handler is not triggering for me.

example - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-roentgen-f03qn?file=/src/App.js